# Connect to Visual Studio Team Services from WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

How can i provide credentials to `TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection`?
I am trying to develop my own WCF Service from witch I will make the request to TFS
I need this WCF service because I would like to manage my TFS files from mobile in witch I cannot use Microsoft.TeamFoundation.* dll

I have been trying this way

```
Uri tpcAddress= new Uri("https://myserver.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection");
TfsConnection tfsc = new TfsConfigurationServer(tpcAddress, 
        new NetworkCredential("mail@example.com", "password"));
TfsWebClient wc = new TfsWebClient(tfsc);
tfsc.Connect(ConnectOptions.IncludeServices);
```

Second try using Custom class derived from ICredentialsProvider

```
ICredentialsProvider prov = new myCredentials();
var tpc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tpcAddress, prov);
tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
tpc.Authenticate();

public class myCredentials : ICredentialsProvider
{
    public ICredentials GetCredentials(Uri uri, ICredentials failedCredentials)
    {
        return new NetworkCredential("mail@example.com", "password");
    }
    public void NotifyCredentialsAuthenticated(Uri uri)
    {
    }
}
```

But it works only in my machine since I am logged in to tfs.

Comment: If you are providing your own WCF service, why don't you run the service as a user (service account) who is already authenticated?

Comment: because i'm trying to make this service for mobile users so that they could access edit delete their elements from their team foundation server

Answer (score 0):

To avoid being prompted for logging in with your Live ID or having to be already signed in, you need to enable Alternate Logon Credentials and use it with your service.

This blog post tells you how:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx

Note that you need to have VS 2012 Update 1 installed to have this feature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Considering this context:
Local machine: Visual Studio 2012 with Update 1
Web Server: Unknown

does the above sample work if i embed the libraries in my webservice?

Answer (score 0):

I recently, found this solution:

```
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(user,pass);

BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(netCred);

TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);

tfsCred.AllowInteractive = false;

TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(path), TFSCred);
```